# \pdftooltip does not work all sentence

Tags: viewers, annotations

MWE

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1mm}
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{black}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\pdftooltip{The international metric system of units or dimensions, commonly called SI, is used in electricity.}{First line works correctly. But other lines is not working.}

\newpage
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\pdftooltip` does not work all sentence. Only first line works correctly. In the first line, the style of the mouse cursor is **pointer** and other lines, the style of the mouse cursor is **auto**.

Can this problem be solved?

**Added to @Mike's solution**

`\partooltip{Find the resistance.}{This works. But there is a right space.} \partooltip{The international metric system of units or dimensions, commonly called SI, is used in electricity.}{First line works correctly. And the other lines now too.}`

`\pdftooltip{Find the resistance.}{This works. But two-sided alignment.} \partooltip{The international metric system of units or dimensions, commonly called SI, is used in electricity.}{First line works correctly. And the other lines now too.}`

`\pdftooltip{Find the resistance.}{This works.} \pdftooltip{The international metric system of units or dimensions, commonly called SI, is used in electricity.}{First line works correctly. But other lines is not working.}`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works for the whole sentence, but internally it's set in a box to measure it's size. And that's done without line breaking. So the tooltip will also pop up in the right column.

[image]

You have two choices:

1. Select one of the other annotations. Some of them even support page breaks.
2. Or set your text in a parbox.

The second option has the disadvantage, that it can only be used for whole paragraphs. Also attention must be payed to the `\parindent`.

This can be put in a macro, so it's as easy to use as `\pdftooltip` itself.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1mm}
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{black}}

\newcommand*{\partooltip}[3][17pt]{% default indent from size11.clo
    \noindent% do not indent the parbox
    \pdftooltip{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
        \hspace*{#1}% simulate the parindent
        #2}}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\pdftooltip{The international metric system of units or dimensions, commonly called SI, is used in electricity.}{First line works correctly. But other lines is not working.}

\partooltip{The international metric system of units or dimensions, commonly called SI, is used in electricity.}{First line works correctly. And the other lines now too.}

\newpage
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is working but I could not fulfill some of my requests. As far as I understand, if the lines of sentence is continuous, the problem will be resolved. I have updated my question, can you check it?

Comment: @Özgür so you need a tooltip for a sentence in the middle of a paragraph. The macro I wrote doesn't provide that. And it can't, because `pdfcomment` uses a box to get the size of the text. Sorry, but here I can't help any further. However, you could try other annotations or check out other packages (or rethink your requirements).

Comment: I will do what I learn from what you write. I will check other packages.